# Handling tasks with different priorities in a thread pool

Tags: java, concurrency, event-handling, threadpool

I have many incoming tasks of priority `A`, `B` and `C` and I want to handle the tasks with a thread pool on a multicore CPU. 70% of the CPU should be used to process 'type `A`' tasks, 20% of the CPU for 'type `B`' tasks  and 10% of the CPU for 'type `C`' tasks.

If however, only tasks of 'type `C`' arrive, then 100% of the CPU should be devoted to them. If only task `B` and `C` arirve then 66% will proccess task `B` and 33% task `C`, etc...

How would you implement this in Java?

p.s:
A priority queue won't work because then only type a tasks will be processed. Also, assigning priorities to threads wont work because its not accurate.

Comment: You often get questions in an interview which have no useful purpose. (Just to see how you think with a new problem, but it new because there is no good reason you would ever do this)  I would make sure I understood what the real business need is because I suspect whatever they are really trying to achieve can be done a better way.  For example enforcing the above scheme is likely to slower down all tasks (with overhead) and you are likely to get better results with something much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should use 3 pools of threads then. 1 pool of 7 threads for A tasks, 1 pool of 2 threads for B tasks, and 1 pool of 1 thread for C tasks.

EDIT: to have parallelism even if there are only C tasks (or, if you have many processors, if you only have B and C tasks), multiply the number of threads in each pool by the number of processors, or the number of processors + 1, or any other bigger factor you like.

Comment: If all tasks are type `C` then how is any parallelism achieved with only 1 `C` thread?

Comment: Multiply the number of threads in each pool by the number of processors (or the number of processors + 1, or any other factor you like). I have edited my answer to indeed take this very valid objection into account.

Comment: This still wouldn't work if type `C` tasks saturate the pool and then a task of type `A` comes along. It's not just about the number of threads...

Comment: Suppose there is 1 processor with 8 cores, you're saying pool `A` should have 56 threads, pool `B` 16 threads, and pool `C` 8 threads? With the same number of such tasks running, the Java thread scheduler could choose to run the 8 `C` threads and put all others on the wait queue. Is your argument that this is fair (in proportion) over time? I was interpreting the question as only have the specified percentages of tasks in a runnable state at any time.

Comment: If all threads have work to do with the CPU, the scheduler should give each thread the same number of time slots on average. Of course, if some tasks are IO-bound rather than CPU-bound, it would change everything.

Comment: Right, but due to this exact reason, the restrictions laid down by the OP are not handled by this solution. If 8 CPU intensive `C` tasks are chugging at the CPU and few tasks of type `A` arrive, it certainly won't honor the "70% CPU to be used by A" invariant because you haven't made the OS aware of this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

this is actually a fairly difficult problem.  basically, you would need to implement a custom blocking queue which tracks not only the pending jobs, but *also* the currently running jobs.  for the pending jobs, i would keep separate lists for the various priority levels.  additionally, you should keep track of the running counts for each priority level.  when a new job is requested from the queue, you need to check the ratio of currently running jobs and choose the next available job from the highest applicable priority (deferring to other priorities if none at the desired priority are available).  obviously, you will need feedback into this queue for your running jobs, so you will probably want to wrap the *actual* jobs with a wrapper Runnable which runs the real job and then updates your queue when that job is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no other processes are running on the CPU, create 3 thread pools, one for each type of task, each pool with as many threads as there are cores on the CPU (so that the entire CPU can be consumed by tasks of any type if only tasks of that type are running). Each new task must pass through a section of code that records how many of each type of tasks are running. If there is a free core on the CPU, immediately launch the new task. If there is no free slot, begin with the lowest priority pool that has lower priority than the new task, and move to the next highest priority pool if necessary with this scan: interrupt/pause a running thread (this assumes that tasks are designed to be interruptable/paused) *if the current pool is exceeding its proportional core usage limit*, wait for that task to finish (another task may finish first, which is just as good). Launch new task in the proper pool. If the new task cannot be launched, it waits in a queue for another thread to complete, freeing up a new slot. When a new slot is freed, a task of the type that just completed gets first priority for the freed slot, if no such task is waiting, then the waiting task with highest priority is launched.

Answer (score 0):

Write a prediction engine that determines statistically the likelyhood that a given task will complete before a task of higher priority arrives. Parameterize by confidence value threshold which is acceptable. The higher the required confidence the more likely you are to under utilize CPU. The lower the threshold the more likely you are to give too much CPU to lower priority tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Interview question I am just suggesting an algorithm how to tackle the problem.

Lets assume we have three separate queues for three types of tasks which means we have three Queues  one for TypeA, other for TypeB, other for Typec.

We can have a queueToprocess lets say it is Qp.

There is a scheduler which which monitors the Qa, Qb, Qc and fills the Qp.

Lets say each **Task** in Qa, Qb, Qc will have a special field which says the number of CPU cycles required to complete the task.

Lets say Qa has three tasks where first task requires 1 clock cycle second task requires three clock cycles ans third requires 3 clock cycles.

Lets say Qb has one task which require 2 clock cycles and Qc has one task which requires 1 clock cycle.

The scheduler will split the task T into small tasks and enques in Qp.

Then Qp will look like Tc, Tb, Ta1, Ta2, Ta2, Ta2, Ta3, Ta3, Ta3.

The processor can deque Qp and execute task.

If someone finds a way to improve this algorithm please correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need here is an hierarchical scheduler that implements shares... your hierarchy looking like this:

```
           CPU
            |
-------------------------
|           |           |
A (70)     B (20)      C (10)
            |
       ---------------
       |  |  |  | |  | 
      T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6
```

Note that I do not display a full hierarchy for A and C but I am sure you got the idea. Now the way to go is to implement a very simple virtual-time based scheduler let's say Start-Time Fair Queuing (SFQ) from Goyal to handle scheduling between A, B and C.

Such a scheduler is work conservative which means that if only tasks from C are present then C as a whole will take the whole thing.

Now to deal with the second level of scheduling you have two ways... Either you implement HSFQ which is an hierarchical version of SFQ or you do a simple round-robin among the thread below A, B and C so that each thread gets a "fair" share of the cycles available to its pool.

I would be careful with round-robin though since fairness is not great if you have mix of population with bursty thread and very greedy thread... Round-robin won't ensure they use the same amount of cycle except if you get into cycle counting which boils down more or less to SFQ.

You can also look at Stride Scheduling more specifically its hierarchical version...

Hope it helps,